# How to select 3 columns from CSV file using java Spark coding also group by and finally sum

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, cloudera

I am New to Spark, I want to write Spark Java program, Like I have to load CSV file which contains 75 columns and 1.4 million rows. while giving the file we have to select only 3 columns, I have to write give condition for that and I have to perform groupbykey for 1 column and I have to do sum of another column

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version of Spark you are running (1.3 or 1.4) you can load the csv-file using Databricks spark-csv package with either:

Spark 1.3

```
val df = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> filePath,"header"->"true"))
```

Spark 1.4

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(Map("path" -> filePath,"header"->"true")).load()
```

In the following I will assume that you are only interested in columns 2, 3 and 32 and that column 2 needs to be parsed as a date, column 3 is an ID of type String and column 32 is an amount that needs to be parsed as a Double.

So, once the file is loaded you can get the 3 columns like this:

```
val allData = df.map(row => (row.getString(3), row.getString(32).toDouble, LocalDate.parse(row.getString(2), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE))
```

(Note that I am using Java LocalDate which is part of Java 8 here. You could use JodaTime instead if you prefer.)

Assuming that you only want rows with a date later than say May 24th, 2015, you can use a filter to get rid of unwanted rows

```
val startDate = LocalDate.of(2015,5,24)
val filteredData = allData.filter{case(_,_,date) => date.isAfter(startDate)}
```

Now, to sum a particular column for each ID, you need to map your data to key-value pairs (ID, amount), and then sum the amount using a `reduceByKey`

```
filteredData.map{case(id,amount, _) => (id, amount)}
            .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank For Your Reply,
But Will you please kindly send the program or any link

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Which program are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a CSV file into spark is to run it with the spark-csv package.

The examples on this webpage should get you what you need, it should only be a few lines:

https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: Hi Any 1 please Tell Me I have this logic java in Mapreduce how can I write in Sark Java.